# How to use GroupBox in C# WPF XAML to wrap only around specific elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to put some elements inside of a `GroupBox` in `C# WPF XAML` code. I'm not sure how to implement it correctly.

Basically I want:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1000">

 <GroupBox Header = "This stuff is in GroupBox ">
   <Label> Label in GroupBox </Label>
   <Label> Some other label in GroupBox  </Label>
 </GroupBox>

 <Label> This is not in the groupbox so don't put me in it! <Label>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Instead of the outermost Grid, use `<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">` Either that or [give the Grid some `RowDefinitions`](http://www.wpftutorial.net/gridlayout.html), and give the GroupBox and the outer Label Grid.Row properties.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: That's an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the outermost `Grid`, use

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"> 
    <GroupBox Header = "This stuff is in GroupBox ">
        <Label> Label in GroupBox </Label>
        <Label> Some other label in GroupBox  </Label>
    </GroupBox>

    <Label> This is not in the groupbox so don't put me in it! <Label>
</StackPanel>
```

Either that or give the `Grid` some RowDefinitions, and give `Grid.Row` properties to the `GroupBox` and the outer `Label`. But the `StackPanel` is quick, and perfect for your case.

Answer (score 2):

Your GroupBox and Label are in the same grid so will lay on top of each other.

Try this:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1000">
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <GroupBox Header = "This stuff is in GroupBox ">
   <Label> Label in GroupBox </Label>
   <Label> Some other label in GroupBox  </Label>
 </GroupBox>

 <Label Grid.Row="1"> This is not in the groupbox so don't put me in it! <Label>

</Grid>
```